# Java cannot find org.apache.tinkerpop import Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I am attempting to connect JanusGraph to Java using Gremlin for Java following this documentation: https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/connecting/java/. There are the dependencies I am using for this:

```
compile "org.janusgraph:janusgraph-driver:0.6.3"
compile "org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-driver:3.5.5"
```

Here is the import statement they used:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal
```

For some reason, my syntax highlighting shows that org.apache.tinkerpop does not exist. The actual error is that the class I am using in my code, `GraphTraversalSource` cannot be found, which I am assuming is because my import statement isn't working properly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

I tried adding other packages like gremlin-core and gremlin-driver in my gradle dependencies, but none of the imports fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the reason this was happening was due to an outdated Gradle version. I had to upgrade to `6.4.1` instead of `5.4.1`. This will allow you to properly pull all Gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The `compile` configuration is deprecated since many many years and since Gradle 7 was finally also removed.
So unless you use an ancient Gradle version, your sync should have failed, telling you that `compile` cannot be found.
Assuming you use a rather recent Gradle version, try using `implementation` instead.

Comment: I changed them both to implementation and it re-downloaded, but I am still getting the cannot find symbol error for GraphTraversalSource.

Comment: Did you import the correct `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource` class? Does it build from the commandline?